# How to install docker community on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: docker, 20.04

When I followed the [community docks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) I came across the following issue:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository \
>    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
>    $(lsb_release -cs) \
>    stable"
[sudo] password for yogesh: 
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]             
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Ign:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Err:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal Release                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 54.182.0.11 443]
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You could consider installing `podman`: OSS, no root required, same CLI as docker...

Comment: As of now, focal is now avaible in the official repositories. So this question is not valid anymore.
https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/

Comment: @Leder thanks for the tip about podman: it's a boon to have such a tool in order to avoid giving docker (by default!) root access to my OS

Answer (score 69):

**Update**: As of 3 AM on May 15, the official Docker repository is available for Ubuntu Focal, so you can follow the [installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) on your Ubuntu to get Docker up and running.

---

Another option is to install Ubuntu-provided version of Docker:

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Long ago there were significant backlashes against this because the package `docker.io` from upstream (Debian) was too old - this is no longer the case. For Focal, `docker.io` is currently (Apr 24, 2020) at `19.03.8-0ubuntu1`, which is satisfactorily new for the majority of Docker workloads.

---

Don't install `docker` by mistake - it used to be the system tray application, which has since been replaced by `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`. The `docker` package can be safely removed had you installed it accidentally.

Comment: This is a great answer. Installing things from Ubuntu repos is probably better than adding 3rd party (like Docker) repos to /etc/apt/sources.list. If things are better now, and Ubuntu keeps a modern version of Docker in their own repos, this is what should be, in my opinion, the preferred approach going forward for installing Docker on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for noting the difference between `docker.io` and `docker-ce` repo. I've been plagued by 3rd party repos in the past -- I'm installing `docker.io` :)

Comment: This worked fine on kubuntu local.

Comment: Unfortunately only containerdio is available right now. See https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/

Comment: @wedi It's no longer the case.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Comment: Now that the focal release is actually completely available, the correct way to add the repo is: 'add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable" ' - the official Docker instructions still point to "/debian" -directory which will not work.

Answer (score 49):

**Release file is available now. Follow the docker community guidelines.**

---

As of today 28, April the release file for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS focal is not available.

So in order to install docker on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS focal release as guided on [docker community link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)

you can change the following command :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

**to**

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   bionic \
   stable"
```

By that what we are doing is we are using bionic (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) release file.

Rest of the commands are okay and will work on 20.04 as well.

Also make sure that you removed the following entry from your **/etc/apt/sources.list** if present before installing docker

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
```

Comment: I assume it is advisable to update the /etc/apt/sources.list entry from bionic to focal once Docker has been added to the 20.04 repos?

Comment: Hey thanks, this indeed solved it for me. Any idea when the official `Focal` repository will be available at the servers of Docker? For some reason I don't like using the `bionic` repo on my fresh Ubuntu 20.04 server :). What are the downsides of using bionic?

Comment: Thank you. This does resolve the issue with `add-apt-repository` which seems to be caused due to a missing **Release** file for Ubuntu 20.04 Focal from Docker. Although @iBug solution seems to be the optimal way to install Docker on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Just a note that the repository `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable` is located at un Ubuntu 20.04 at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`. This needs to be removed before attempting to install docker in other ways.

Answer (score 3):

You can install it using a single command

`sudo apt install docker-compose`

Comment: Yes @karel, you are right, but I found this single command to be more user friendly for beginners.

Comment: No @karel. It also installs packages 'containerd' and stack of python3 packages, like 'python3-docker'. The docker works on my PC right after that. But it did not work after installing `docker.io`, or `sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io` from the `disco` and `bionic` repositories.

Comment: @bl79 You dont need to install anything more. Just install `docker-compose` and it will install all its dependencies itself.

Comment: that's what I said.

Comment: @bl79 I'm not sure if I'm right with this, but I think the `docker-compose` version is an Ubuntu package, as the `docker` package, while `docker.io` is shipped by the docker team itself. Due to that, `docker-compose` matchs the `docker` package version, but is outdated respect to `docker.io`. That's why, in Ubuntu 20.04, a docker-compose.yml file with version 3.8 is rejected by the `docker-compose` Ubuntu package; however, docker-compose file format 3.8 is right one respect to the `docker.io` version.

Answer (score 2):

Following steps can help you:

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Open /etc/apt/sources.list file by running

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment out the following line:

```
#deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
```

Press Ctrl+o to save, ctrl+x to close.

[image]
Run the following command to install docker:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Running the above command will successfully install docker:

[image]

You can verify the docker version to confirm if it has been installed successfully:

```
docker -v
```

[image]

EDIT:

If you are on AWS EC2 just run the following command and it will install the Docker there:

```
sudo apt install docker.io 
sudo systemctl enable --now docker
```

Comment: This isn't any different from the first answer.

Comment: Right, added more details with screenshots for more clarification.

Comment: There is no need for all that luckily. Just run: sudo apt-get install docker.io on Ubunto 20.04. I hope this help you.