# Installing docker with snap and apt-get

Tags: apt, snap, docker

I'm trying to install docker on my Ubuntu 20.04. Trying install docker with `apt-get` and `snap`:

```
sudo apt-get install docker
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  wmdocker
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docker wmdocker
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/14.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 58.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package wmdocker.
(Reading database ... 193518 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../wmdocker_1.5-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wmdocker (1.5-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/docker_1.5-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking docker (1.5-2) ...
Setting up wmdocker (1.5-2) ...
Setting up docker (1.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

If I run docker command I get error:

```
a@ubuntu:~$ docker

Command 'docker' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install docker     # version 19.03.11, or
sudo apt  install docker.io  # version 19.03.8-0ubuntu1.20.04.1

See 'snap info docker' for additional versions.
```

Why system can't find docker command?

Then I tied snap:

```
sudo snap install docker
```

And docker command run fine.

Why I can install docker with snap and can't with apt-get ?

Answer (score 7):

Because [that `docker`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/docker.1.html) is not the [docker you expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)). `docker` is the package name of system tray  for KDE3/GNOME2. You can verify that by visiting [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=docker&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) or by running

```
apt show docker
```

The error message you got while running `docker` from terminal gives a brief idea about this confusion.

To install the docker you expected, refer to [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) or see [How to install docker community on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1230189/816190)

Comment: `docker.io` is Docker package in APT!

Comment: @N0rbert Though Ubuntu's official repository contains docker as `docker.io`, [docker's official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) states, *"Older versions of Docker were called `docker`, `docker.io`, or `docker-engine`"*. And the very first step is to remove them. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Anyway with Docker's repository you can have latest version in Xenial Xerus which is not the case with `docker.io`.

Comment: Agree that *`docker`* name confuses the user. But `docker.io` is working normally when installed :)

Comment: If it is not the real docker how it can pull images, and run them? I just installed the docker via snap `sudo snap install docker` and it can run hello-world `docker run hello-world`

Comment: @AVarf I believe you misread the question as well as answer. In the question as well, vico confirmed that snap version was working fine which I never denied. My answer was related to the docker installed using APT.

Comment: I am sure I read the Q correctly since I have the same problem and because of some firewall I can't install docker via apt but I am able to install it via snap. Maybe I misunderstood your answer. The only thing I want to know is what are the differences between docker installed via apt and snap? One I could find is when installed via snap there is no docker.service (`Unit docker.service could not be found.`)

Comment: @AVarf APT installs deb packages. Snaps and debs differ functionally. See https://snapcraft.io/blog/a-technical-comparison-between-snaps-and-debs. For service not found issue, on a quick Google search, I found this https://askubuntu.com/q/977961